# Example website for WCAG 1.4.1 Use of color

Tags: accessibility

I need some example website that explains about 1.4.1 use of color.
My understanding that the application / website should not indicate via color on text as it cannot understand for the blind user.
guideline 1.3.3 sensory characteristics also tells about content do not rely on color.
what is the difference between both guideline ? anyone pls provide any example site for better understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly! I can provide you with an example website that demonstrates the WCAG 1.4.1 Use of Color guideline. The guideline states that color should not be the sole means of conveying information or indicating an action, as it can create barriers for users who are blind or have color vision deficiencies. Let's also explore the difference between WCAG 1.4.1 and guideline 1.3.3.

WCAG 1.4.1 Use of Color:
This guideline specifically focuses on the use of color in web content. It states that color should not be used as the only visual means to convey information, indicate an action, or distinguish elements. The intention is to ensure that individuals with visual impairments or color vision deficiencies can understand and interact with the content effectively, even without relying on color cues.

Example Website: Consider a website that has a registration form with required fields marked in red color. However, there is no accompanying text or other visual indicators to convey that these fields are mandatory. This would violate the WCAG 1.4.1 guideline, as the use of color alone to indicate the mandatory status excludes individuals who cannot perceive the color red.

On the other hand,

WCAG 1.3.3 Sensory Characteristics:
This guideline addresses content that relies solely on sensory characteristics (other than color) to convey information or functionality. It emphasizes that web content should not rely on sensory characteristics, such as shape, size, visual location, or sound alone, to communicate important information or interact with the content. The purpose is to ensure that individuals who may have limitations in perceiving or understanding certain sensory cues can still access and comprehend the content.

The difference between WCAG 1.4.1 and guideline 1.3.3 lies in their specific focus. WCAG 1.4.1 specifically deals with the use of color as a visual indicator, while guideline 1.3.3 encompasses other sensory characteristics apart from color.

Example Website: Consider a website where clicking on a button triggers a sound effect without any accompanying text or visual indication of the button's functionality. This would violate the WCAG 1.3.3 guideline, as the interaction relies solely on the auditory characteristic of the sound, excluding users who cannot perceive or hear the sound.

To gain a better understanding of these guidelines and how they are implemented, you can visit the Web Accessibility Initiative's (WAI) website at [www.w3.org/WAI/](http://www.w3.org/WAI/). They provide comprehensive information and examples related to WCAG guidelines, including 1.4.1 Use of Color and 1.3.3 Sensory Characteristics.

Comment: This helps a lot. The simpke examples really clarify the confusion.

Comment: @IAmMilinPatel Could not find example from this site www.w3.org/WAI/.. can you pls help me to find the example

Comment: https://www.w3.org/WAI/search/?q=1.4.1 You might need to look the guigelines up and navigate through the links to find. Couple of examples: https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/use-of-color    https://www.w3.org/WAI/tips/designing/   https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/quickref/?showtechniques=141#use-of-color